# What is the origin of energy emitted as radiation by an electrically charged object stationary around a massive object?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, energy, electromagnetic-radiation, energy-conservation

Einstein's special relativity tells us that laws of physics are the same in all
intertial frames. General relativity futher extends this by stating that
reference frames that are in free fall around massive objects are inertial, but
that reference frames that are stationary around massive objects are not
inertial. There is no experiment that could distinguish one inertial reference
frame from another, and no black-box experiment that could distinguish
stationary reference frame around a massive object from one that is inside an
accelerating rocket in space unless you are permitted to look out of that black
box.

All charged particles in accelerating motion emit electromagnetic radiation.
Because gravity is not a force, if we place a modern smartphone with
accelerometer on a table, the only force the smartphone experiences is the
normal force that keeps it from being in free fall. The smartphone
accelerometer agrees: the 3-axis accelerometer tells that it's in accelerating
motion. The reason for acceleration is that it is not traveling in a straight
line through spacetime because spacetime around the earth is curved.

Let us charge the smartphone on a table with static electricity (NB: not with chemical energy stored in battery). Because it is
now electrically charged, and because it is in accelerating motion, it must
emit electromagnetic radiation, right? Otherwise we could distinguish a
smartphone on a table from a smartphone in an accelerating rocket.

Let us also assume for the purposes of this thought experiment that we stop the
rotation of the earth. The electromagnetic radiation that this electrically
charged smartphone on a table emits must have some origin. It can't be the
smartphone battery since for the purposes of this thought experiment, we can
remove the battery. It can't be the rotation of the earth, since we assumed it
has been stopped.

Since the smartphone is continuously accelerating, forever, as long as you
don't destroy the test setup, it must be continuously emitting electromagnetic
radiation, right? Why wouldn't it be a perpetual motion machine of the first
kind then since we can extract the energy from that electromagnetic radiation
and do useful work with it?

I used smartphone as an example here because smartphones have accelerometers that clearly
demonstrate that a smartphone on a table is in continuous accelerating motion.
Of course we can replace the smartphone with anything that can hold a charge of
static electricity and that can be held stationary on a table so it won't be in free fall.

Comment: The basic premise of the question: *All charged particles in accelerating motion emit electromagnetic radiation* is false even in flat spacetime if we consider situations with more than one point charge. EM radiation is a *global* phenomenon, so knowing just the local motion of a single charge is not enough to decide whether radiation is emitted.

Comment: I think that you are describing the [paradox of radiation of charged particles in a gravitational field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_of_radiation_of_charged_particles_in_a_gravitational_field)